# Bulk posts in Wordpress with wp_insert_posts begins to be very slow after 100k Posts

Tags: wordpress, performance

I'm using wp_insert_post() function to bulk publish new posts on my website. I have started around one week ago and everything works very fast with an average of around 80 new posts per minute. Day by day, by the increasing of the number of published posts, the average of the published posts per minute by the function decreased.

Now I have over 100k published posts and the average is 5 new published posts per minute.

The function that I'm using is very simple:

```
   // Gather post data.
   $new_video = array(
       'post_type'     => 'video',
       'post_title'    => $title,
       'post_status'   => $status,
       'post_author'   => $author,
       'post_date'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),  
       'post_date_gmt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
       'post_category' => explode(',', $category),
       'post_name'     => $rand_video_id
   );

   // Insert the video into the database.
   wp_insert_post( $new_video );
```

After the post insert I also set some terms and some post metas. By reading on the web I have find different solution to increase the speed of the wp_insert_post function and first of all this one:

```
wp_defer_term_counting(false);
```

Of course, an excellent solution to not loose time to count the terms but unfortunately I don't see any improvement.

I have also try to clear the function, and remove all insert of post tags, custom taxonomies and metas but it has no speed effect.

Someone have any suggestion? Thank you

**** Issue Fixed ****

The problem was fixed by deactivating a WP plugin used to generate the .xml sitemap - Now everything is back to be very fast and the average of new posts per minute is back to 80.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add true to them like this, plus you can also turn off comment counting which can also help speed things up.

```
wp_defer_term_counting( true );
wp_defer_comment_counting( true )
```

Then after you have completed the input set them back to false.

```
wp_defer_term_counting( false );
wp_defer_comment_counting( false );
```

These also need to be above your code which has the `wp_insert_post()` function otherwise it won't work.

With these set to true, it should help somewhat, with 100K posts though there is a lot of background process and DB work which will naturally slow down updates. The next thing would be to look at the indexing on the WP tables in the DB. As optimising these at the size you have is important.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I have already try this options and also just try it again but without good results. It continue to have an average of 5 posts per minute without any increasing of speed. Can I ask you what do you mean about the indexing on the WP tables?

Comment: I have just finished to optimise all the tables from phpMyAdmin and also with the WP tool that can be enabled with ( OPTIMIZE TABLE 'wp_posts' ) - Also this doesn't help and the average continues to be 5 per minute.

Comment: If I have a for loop to loop my files, then after `wp_insert_post()` I have other function such as insert attachment, when exact should I set to true and false? Before the loop, or right before `wp_insert_post()`? And set to false right after the wp_insert_post or after the loop? Can I set it once instead of set it every time `wp_insert_post`? Because I have other wordpress function after inserting post